# how to nest jsx code in js, which nested in jsx?

Tags: reactjs

what's wrong with this code?

```
          {(canEditFile && !err) && 
            ( isSaving ? 
              <button type={'button'} className={'btn btn-icon btn-secondary btn-active'}>
                <i className={'fa fa-spin fa-spinner'}/></button> :
              <IconButton 
                text={gettext('Save')} 
                id={'saveButton'} 
                icon={'fa fa-save'}  
                // button imported in this file does not have functionalities of 
                // disabled, isActive as button imported in markdowneditor has
                //disabled={isContentChanged} 
                //isActive={!isContentChanged}
                onClick={this.props.onSaveChangedContent} 
              />
            )
          }
```

WebpackError at /
            ModuleError in

Line 105:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ,

103 |              :
  104 |

> 105 |               text={gettext('Save')} 
>         |               ^
>     106 |               id={'saveButton'}

Comment: You're missing the other half of your ternary `isSaving ? _yourThing_ : _thisIsMissing_`.  Also, not sure if it's just what I'm used to or a jsx thing, but I usually wrap a chunk of code with () - `(<button type=........</button<)`.  Additionally, if the value of your prop is just a string no need to use curly braces, just pass a string.  `id={'saveButton'}` should be `id="saveButton"`

Comment: i solved this problem, i forget to compile my new code, which is correct.